# SharePoint Workspace not opening files

Tags: sharepoint-workspace

SharePoint Workspace 2010 is unable to open files such as Visio or Zip. However, I can open documents (doc, docx).

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "not opening"? not opening in browser, not opening in client application, only gets a Save-dialog? :)

Comment: Not opening in Client Application. When double clicking a file I see the progress bar start and stop but then nothing happens.